# Unity NavMeshBuilder not working with sprite sheets

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

does Navigation Surface work with spritesheets? I am using NGUI sprites for the NavMesh agent and i get an error on baking '"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh'. If i switch to Sprite Renderer, the error goes away. But i really need to use NGUI spritesheet. I tried switching Use Geometry to Physics colliders but that does not work either although I have colliders on my gameobjects.